# Is there a way to get DataNode's DiskUsage using java client?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, diskspace, datanode

I want to get disk-usage status of a DataNode over RPC/ Java Client. I know there is a way using WebAPI and parsing the response.
But, I am looking for RPC based approach only.